# how to select a string randomly in Android?

Tags: java, android, string

i am working with a quiz app so every time when an activity starts  the text view in it should be different questions which is randomly selected from strings
what i have exactly done now is: 
I have text view in an activity and i have certain strings in values. what should i do to display a different string when each time the activity is started. Can any one help me?

Comment: what you had tried.?

Comment: Put the Strings in an Array, then generate a random index.

Comment: Random r = new Random(); int randomNo = r.nextInt(String Array Length);

Answer (score 0):

```
    static final String AB = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    static Random rnd = new Random();

    String randomString( int len ) 
    {
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( len );
       for( int i = 0; i < len; i++ ) 
          sb.append( AB.charAt( rnd.nextInt(AB.length()) ) );
       return sb.toString();
    }
String random_st=randomString(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an array containing all the ids of your string resources, and select a random number each time activity starts.
Something like:

```
int arr[] = new int[]{R.string.str1, R.string.str2};
@override 
public void onCreate(Bundle data) {
    Random r = new Random(arr.length);
    //TextView.setText(getResources().getString(arr[r.nextInt()]);
}
```